# How to make nuclear fireworks?

Tags: science-based, nuclear-weapons, colors

Meg Al O'man, empress of all the lands where the sun never sets, bringer of peace across the oceans, archmaster of the secret order of the water puppets and so on and so forth has set her mind on celebrating her upcoming jubileum  in a spectacular fashion: instead of commoners' fireworks and their plebian black powder, she wants to have nuclear fireworks, and has tasked her master of ceremonies with having them developed.

Her requirements:

- there must be a nuclear explosion
- the yield of the explosion doesn't matter
- eventual casualties among the commoners following the firework show are no concern
- for all the spectators, the fireworks shall not only go KAHBOOM, but also display at least 3 different colors
- any other effect is a nice to have

Is there a way for the master of ceremonies to fulfill these requirements and see the day after the jubileum?

Comment: "eventual casualties following the firework show are no concern" does this include the Empress herself? Looking at a nuclear firework which is too close without protection may result in loss of vision, even at otherwise safe ranges.

Comment: "display at least 3 different colors" - it will display bright white light, infrared and a gama-ray burst. Does that count as colors?

Comment: You could MAYBE create a colorfull mushroom cloud, by distributing large amount of heat resistant pigment in area surrounding the explosion, so it could be pulled upwards with the rising air streams.

Comment: nuclear explosion✔️ largest yield (nearest to Earth)✔️ 0 casualty (ignore skin cancer)✔️ >3 different color spectrums (black body)✔️other effect such superman ability (make vitamin D)✔️ all you need is a pair of SUNglasses and wait until noon ;D

Comment: Maybe also luminescent pigments producing different light wavelengths, charged by radiation, so the cloud will shine after primary light burst will fade (for night explosions)

Comment: Do the colors have to be visible to everyone, or just Her Majesty?

Comment: How would they know it isn't just [100 tons of TNT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VANyY87-_Q&t=83s)?

Comment: @Mazura The radiation

Comment: Call Douglas Adams.\* Maybe he can set you up with the promoters for Disaster Area—The rock'n'roll band whose fans generally agree that the best seats at a Disaster Area show are in heavily reinforced underground bunkers, approximately ten miles from the stage. \[\*Unfortunately, you're going to need help from a spirit medium to place that call.]

Comment: Assuming this dynasty could survive for at least 99 generations while making decisions like that, your ruler could be Empress Meg Al O'man IC.  (No 'A' in roman numerals, unfortunately.)

Comment: The sun never sets? When do they plan to enjoy these fireworks?

Comment: @komodosp The sun can't set when you regularly make your own

Answer (score 39):

The [B-54 SADM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Atomic_Demolition_Munition) shows that an atomic weapon can have a yield of as little as 10 tons of TNT.  As this device was a variable yield weapon, from 10 to 1000 tons of TNT, it should be possible to make a smaller, simpler single-yield device.  That device will form the core of the fireworks display.

Of course, when detonated, an atomic weapon produces high-temperature black-body radiation, which is pretty much a boring blue-white colour suitable only for causing retinal damage and radiation burns... not at all what we want for an exciting fireworks display.  However, there is a solution.

If you have the technology to make an atomic weapon, that means that you likely have all sorts of other technologies, including the ability to make rockets and  a wide variety of chemicals.  If you have those abilities, you can combine rockets with an assortment of [phosphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor) and launch them prior to the launch of the atomic weapon.

These phosphor rockets would contain a variety of coloured powdered phosphors.  They would be launched on pre-determined trajectories, and as they fly, they would release their powdered phosphors into the air in a pre-set sequence.

After the phosphor rockets were launched, the low-yield nuke could be detonated some distance behind the phosphor rockets, shortly after the phosphor rockets had released their payload.  The nuke need not be in direct line of sight to  the audience at all, as long as it is in line of sight to the phosphor dust trails.

The energetic radiation from the atomic device would excite the phosphor powders in the atmosphere, which would cause them to glow with their characteristic colours, before the shock wave from the atomic device disturbed the display.

With proper preparation, this could be repeated in the same volume many times.  In effect, you could have a huge, rocket-launched, low-refresh-frequency, bomb-pumped screen in mid-air, like some sort of sci-fi holographic device, but real.  It would be able to display as many colours as you could mix phosphors to display, at least as many as an old-fashioned cathode-ray television tube could display, with the advantage that you could use this setup to display all sorts of propaganda, and show how much the Empress likes over-the-top displays of her might.

That some of these phosphors contain toxic heavy metals like Cadmium or Strontium, and may become radioactive after their extreme excitation is apparently of little concern to the Empress, who would probably view this from a safe distance in a sealed bunker, and not care about the effects on her admiring populace.

Comment: Re, "B-54 SADM..." I don't suppose you could find any old [Davy Crocketts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Crockett_(nuclear_device)), at your local army surplus store? Unlike the SADM, which was meant to be placed near a target by a team of commandos, the Davy Crockett comes with a rocket that launches the warhead into the sky.

Comment: @SolomonSlow 155mm [W48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W48), [W82](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W82), or equivalent 152mm Soviet nuclear artillery shells would be a much safer choice for the operators than a Davy Crockett due to having firing ranges much larger than their area of effect.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The SADM is just an example of a very low yield device.  I'm not suggesting to actually use one, just that it represents a known lower limit to the yield that could be achieved in a practical device.

Answer (score 25):

## Starfish Double Prime

[image]

*"We are most amused"  ([image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Fishbowl))*

The nuclear test shot [Starfish Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish_Prime) was in many ways very successful, especially since the weapon detonated with a yield close to predicted.

But, more relevant to your question: Starfish Prime also created *spectacular* auroras, in areas where auroras are otherwise pretty much never seen.

The appearance of the aurora was described such:

> Growth of the auroral region to the north was by addition of new lines developing from west to east. The white-yellow auroral streamers receded upward from the horizon to the north and grew to the south and at about 2 minutes the white-yellow bands were still about 10 degrees wide and extended mainly from near zenith to the south.

So, here you have what Her Royal Doucheness are looking for: a nuclear boom that creates a multi-colour light show.

However...

Starfish Prime also introduced the world to the concept of "[Nuclear Electromagnetic Pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse)" — a concept that would then be endlessly misrepresented by Hollywood (*) — as it knocked out satellites, phone exchanges, and caused loads of similar problems for electronics over a very wide area. This was not expected to happen; the expected EMP was thought to become much smaller. But such things happen when hairless monkeys take the smallest rocks they can find and bash them together with the greatest force they can muster.

### "What about radioactive fallout?"

This will be entirely negligible. First, it is away from the ground and the atmosphere, meaning no neutron activation of various elements (otherwise a major source of radioactive substances). Second, the resulting fission products of the weapon will be dispersed and diluted before they make their way to the ground, and be noticed merely as slightly anomalous readings of the [background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation).

---

So, how would Princess Meg get her nuclear fireworks?

By means of a nuclear warhead in the megatonne range, detonated at a few hundred kilometers altitude. This will create a magnificently bright double flash, followed by approximately two minutes of a very colourful and spectacular aurora.

What will the negative effects be?

Total havoc in power grids and communication networks, and — if Meg's society has have made it into the digital age, with integrated circuits being commonplace — broken electronics everywhere.

---

(*) Hollywood depicts *all* nuclear explosions as causing an EMP. This is not true, the charged particles must be given time to spiral along the magnetic field lines of the Earth for tens of kilometers. But deep in the atmosphere, they are not given time to do that before they smack into air molecules and just stop.

Comment: All the EMP means is no more distractions from the Empress's light show. So, double plus!

Comment: +1 for the "hairless monkeys" sentence.

Comment: @zovits Actually we are hairless _apes_ — we belong to the taxonomical superfamily [Hominidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape), which are commonly called the "apes" — but "hairless monkeys" just sounds funnier. Plus I am a fan of the Craig Alanson bookseries "Expeditionary Force" and the (other) main protagonist of that series keeps referring to humans as "screeching/smelly/stupid monkeys". :D

Comment: @MichaelK Something you want to be very fastidious about getting correct around orangutans, and one in particular.

Comment: @Pilchard123 Oh, I just Mandela-effected myself... I thought Thade said that, but it was  Krull. Is he not a gorilla?

Comment: @MichaelK I was more thinking of [The Librarian](https://wiki.lspace.org/Librarian). He is... very insistent that people know that he is an ape and not a monkey.

Comment: @Pilchard123 Oooh! Damn, I need up up my Discworld game.

Answer (score 6):

This is a fun one, not necessarily because it's a good idea, but because there's a significant similarity between nuclear devices and fireworks. Your standard "Fat Man" style nuke isn't just a big boom. It's a lot of little booms that surround and set off a big boom. It's actually the exact opposite of a firework, where the central firework sets off a bunch of surrounding little ones.

[image: Nuclear Firework]

So, for this event, let's do both. We'll also throw in a couple of other known technologies. The original Orion project was basically a spaceship that threw a bomb out the back and caught the explosion on a steel blast plate. Although I don't know if it's related, the fastest known human-propelled object was a manhole cover sitting on top of a nuke.

So let's surround our nuclear bomb with a shell of manhole covers.

We want a geodesic shell in two layers. The first is a heavy neutron-absorbing layer of lead that will completely vaporize, maybe a couple of inches thick, acting as a propellant. Outside of that, we want a couple of feet of material that will burn hot while ignited, throwing a lot of sparks. Raw phosphorus should do the trick.

I recommend you blow this one off outside the atmosphere. Not necessarily to prevent damage, but because they'll be able to see it from thousands of miles away. Also, the auroras will be nice.

Comment: Would phosphorus burn outside the atmosphere? I think it needs oxygen for that.

Comment: @zovits, Good point. I tacked that last paragraph on as an after-thought. For out-of-atmosphere purposes, you'd need to build something more like a rocket.

Answer (score 3):

It seems entirely practical. Not all nuclear explosives are city busters, there exist tactical nuclear weapons with explosive power about 1 tonne which is less than large conventional explosive weapons like MOAB.

So wrap a TNW cannon shell in copper (blue) potassium (pink) or sodium (yellow) and you will get the colour of ionised metal in the explosion.

Comment: Hm... will not the fireball obscure the pretty colours? The fireball is from EM radiation heating the air. Is there not a risk that this will wrap around the glow of the ionised metal?

Answer (score 1):

Her Most Highly Esteemed Majesty Empress O'man,

I have developed a most exquisite solution to your issue of not having enough "bang" in your fireworks displays, as you put it. Your neglect of the safety of your subjects is... well, I don't really mind, but I would think that they would mind quite a bit, and in order to prevent the rabblerousers from attempting a most heinous takeover of the empire, I have devised a device that meets all of your requirements and which I can begin manufacture of within three business days: **fusion plasma bombs.**

The bombs operate on the principle of nuclear fusion. Within each warhead is loaded a low-yield fission bomb (no more than 1 kiloton of TNT) along with a large amount of highly-pressurized hydrogen. When the fission bomb is detonated, a small amount of tritium is injected into the hydrogen gas to initiate a fusion reaction along with the heat of the accompanying nuclear explosion (although I'm sure you're already familiar with how fusion weapons work).

Not only does this meet the requirements of producing a nuclear fireball, but by carefully tuning the yield of the fission bomb and the mechanism by which fusion is initiated, different plasma colors can be generated by the fusion explosion: each corresponding to a frequency on hydrogen's line spectrum (one a crimson red, one a light cyan, and one a deep purple), the plasmas generated by the fusion fireballs are forced outwards from the nuclear explosion, producing a nova of color around the initial fission fireball that I believe should appease Her Pristine Highness.

As far as delivery goes, any of Her Gloriousness's missiles from her personal armory should do. Hydrogen being as light as it is, the only real payload is the fission bomb which is in turn very light due to its small yield. For additional effect, the missiles can be programmed to fly into the upper stratosphere and detonate, allowing the fusion plasmas to interact with the magnetosphere and create an artificial "Northern Lights" phenomenon with each detonation.

Sincerely,
Your Humble Master of Ceremonies